# Donation/money pool online?

Tags: webapp-rec

What site can I use to create a donation pool? I want to display how much money is raised in realtime. I have seen one for charities only, which this is not. I also found [Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/) which looked good but it doesn't seem to be friendly to non US donators and requires the project host to live in the U.S. which I do not.

It looks like [Paypal](http://www.paypal.com) supports it but I am unsure if it displays in realtime. I'd like a way to return all money if the donation target isn't met, however this isn't a requirement.

[Chipin](http://www.chipin.com/) Looks like a good alternative but had no news for a while
[Pledge Bank](http://www.pledgebank.com/) doesn't look as good but may be suitable.

What else is there?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal's [Facebook and MySpace badges](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/general/OctEmailLP-outside), appear to update realtime.
You can also check their [generic HTML badges](http://giving.paypallabs.com/). Better check their [FAQ](https://giving.paypallabs.com/widget_faq.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ChipIn in the past, not sure why you care about recent news about them.  I don't know if it supports returning all the donations when a goal isn't met, though.

Answer (score 0):

WePay is what you're looking for:

https://www.wepay.com/

> Yesterday, we pushed a feature,
>   inspired specifically for the Reddit
>   community, intended to make it even
>   easier. In your group account
>   settings, you can enable the account
>   so anybody can join, without you
>   having to invite them first. The basic
>   idea being that you can maintain full
>   transparency, since everybody can see
>   where the money is going. If the money
>   isn't being allocated appropriately,
>   anybody can cry foul. Everyone on
>   Reddit can join if they’d like. Every
>   time the account reaches $100, you can
>   demand that the money be sent directly
>   to the beneficiary. As a member of the
>   account, you can monitor this. If the
>   account balance ever exceeds one or
>   two hundred dollars, and the money
>   doesn't go to the right place, you can
>   simply refuse to donate (and tell
>   everybody else to do the same).

http://www.reddit.com/r/self/comments/f5vh1/i_founded_the_antipaypal_raised_9mm_and_now_want/

Alas, they are yet to catch up to the rest of the world (US donors only), but they might be able to support non-us payouts -do check them out.